# Congruence and modular arithmetics

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I started to study number theory and got stuck in the following exercise:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $ab\equiv lcm(a,b)(\mbox{mod gcd}(a,b))$.

I have no idea how to show that. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Some advice to the OP: When you have no idea how to go about solving a problem, try looking at some examples.  Pick some values for $a$ and $b$ that have "interesting" lcm's and/or gcd's, check if the congruence holds, and look for patterns. At the very least it'll give you something to do while your subconscious if quietly at work.

Comment: @Barry And also make sure you confirm the answer to yourself before you claim anything

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg, agreed! But also, don't worry about making mistakes.  If you don't make the occasional mistake, it's probably because you're not doing much of anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$a,b$ are both divisible by $gcd(a,b)$ so $ab\equiv0  \pmod {gcd(a,b)}$.
the $lcm$ is $kab$ where $k$ is a real number for witch  $kab \geq a$ if $a<b$
and $gcd \leq a$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Let $d=gcd(a,b)$ and $m=lcm(a,b)$. Write $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$. Write $m$ in terms of $a',b',d$.